# How to change the header on parent component according to route

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-routing

Using Angular 7.x, I want to change my parent header component accordingly to the child routes and if they're activated or not. So in my case

```
AppComponent   
     Feature Module <= detect changes here    
          Child Components of feature module
```

So my routing is very simple, the app-routing.module just  contains the loading of the feature module with loadChildren, nothing fancy here.

Then this feature module contains the routes for the child components. There is one parentComponent, we call it `ParentComponent` which contains the router-outlet. There is also some headers that I want to change accordingly to the childs.

SO i have two child components: `create`, and '`:id'` (detail page). When I trigger these routes I need the parent component to just change their text content accordingly. So for example when the create page is triggered I want to add the header: "Create new item", and for the :id page I want to show "Detail page".

Now, I have figured out I need to subscribe to the router events or on the activatedRoute (or snapshot). I'm at a loss here so I don't really know what to do here.

My parent component looks like this now:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Parent Title';
  // Check if it is possible to change the title according to the route
  subtitle = 'Parent subtitle';

  constructor(private readonly router: Router, private readonly route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.url.subscribe(data => {
      if (this.route.snapshot.firstChild) {
        console.log('yes', this.route.snapshot.firstChild);
        // Change header with a if/else or switch case here
      } else {
        // Display standard text 
        console.log('no');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

this is the output of the console.logs, notice in my real application the parent is named 'timesheets'.

[image]

Is there maybe another solution for this? Maybe a service, but all of the information is basically in the route already, so I'm trying to figure out if this is the way to go for my problem.

Comment: What version of Angular do you use?

Comment: I'm using angular 7

Comment: is the title on the header is a constant for a particular child???

Comment: The title (h1) is just a variable being used to use it int parent.component.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can listen `NavigationEnd` events in `ParentComponent` or (I think) even better you can use a title service.

---

Solution 1:

In `ParentComponent`

```
import {NavigationEnd, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {filter} from 'rxjs/operators';
...



constructor(private router: Router, private readonly route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.subscribeRouterEvents();

}

subscribeRouterEvents = () => {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe(() => {

       this.title = this.route.snapshot.data['title'];
       // Assuming your route is like:
       // {path: 'path', component: MyComponent, data: { title: 'Page Title'}}
    });
```

---

Solution 2:

Using `TitleService`. Create a service that holds the page title, subscribe to title from `ParentComponent` and send new title to service from `ChildComponent`.

**TitleService**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TitleService {

  private defaultTitle = 'Page Title';
  private titleSubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(this.defaultTitle);
  public title: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private titleService: Title) {
    this.title = this.titleSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public setTitle(title: string) {
    this.titleSubject.next(title);
  }
}
```

**ParentComponent**

```
pageTitle = 'Page Title';
constructor(private titleService: TitleService) {}

ngOnInit(){
  this.titleService.title.subscribe(value => this.pageTitle = value);
}
```

**ChildComponent**

```
pageTitle = 'Child Component Title';
constructor(private titleService: TitleService) {}

ngOnInit(){
  this.titleService.setTitle(this.pageTitle);
}
```

Comment: I think the answer @aries12 gave is a little less verbose and suffice my requirements. But I appreciate this solution equally.

Comment: I think there is an error in the other answer. `subscribe` method returns a `subscription`, not the value you get in callback. Therefore assigning `subscription` to the title is not what you need.

Comment: I receive all of the data from the route.data and I can get the title from it, and assign it to the title variable I use. It works sufficiently to what I need.

Comment: The problem is not there. The problem is with the line `this.title = this.route.data.subscribe(x => console.log(x));` It should be 
 `this.route.data.subscribe(x => this.title = x.header_title);`

Comment: My apologies, I didn't read you had two solutions. You're right, I changed that this.title = subscription ofcourse accordingly but because your answer is more worked out and works out of the box. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: No worries :) Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the title for a child as part of route like this.

```
const routes: Routes =[
  {
    path: 'create',
    component: SomeComponent,
    data : {header_title : 'some title'}
  },
];

ngOnInit() {
   this.title = this.route.data.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
}
```

and get the title in the child component and set that as header title using a service.